# How to increase width of Chrome's bookmark dropdown menu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have many bookmarks with long titles stored in Chrome bookmark folders. When I click a bookmark folder in Chrome's bookmark bar, the dropdown menu that pops up to list the bookmarks is not very wide. As a result, I can't see the full title length of many of the bookmarks.

Strangely, Chrome is only using a tenth of my screen width for the menu when it could use more to display the long titles. I'd like to customize that dropdown menu width to show more of the bookmark titles. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can use this chrome extension [Fast Bookmark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fast-bookmark/bkolccbclokgkhcciikgbkcmnagimjib)

Answer (score -1):

As of Chrome Browser version 72.0.3626.121, there is no standard setting or tool to alter the bookmark folder drop-down box.